# Specify outgoing address for cron messages with postfix

Tags: postfix, cron, gentoo

I have a server with Gentoo and Postfix. Postfix is configured so that all e-mail messages are routed through an external relay which requires a particular address in 'From'.

From `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
relayhost = relay.example.com
```

I also have a cron task, which I'd like to send e-mail from. But the 'From' address is 'user@hostname', which is not allowed on a relay. Is it possible to substitute the correct address to cron for sending messages or fix the Postfix configuration in some way?

Comment: What is the command that you are using to send the emails?

Comment: There is no command, just MAILTO='' in a crontab file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use vixie-cron and ssmtp for a similar situation. What I do, especially for root jobs, is pipe the output of the command through `| mail -r "required_user@external-domain.com" target_user@wherever.com`; it's tedious but it works.

Comment: Yes, I also have vixie-cron. Unfortunatelly this is a custom built VDS even without 'mail' command. Finally I wrap the call to my task in php which captures output and emails it. You solution should work too, so I mark it as an answer.